# Variation of Cauchy integral formula?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $f$ be analytic on an open set $U$ and $a \in U, f'(a)\neq0$.

Prove that $\frac{1}{f'(a)}= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{dz}{f(z)-f'(a)}$ .

My attempt: Since $f'(a)\neq 0$, $f$ is bijective on some neighborhood of $a$. Let $g$ be such local inverse of $f$ and $f(a)=b$. Then $\frac {1}{f'(a)}=g'(b)=\int_C \frac{g(z)dz}{(z-a)^2}$, and I got stuck here.

Is my attempt correct? Or should I seek another way to prove?

Comment: The mix "$f(z)-f'(a)$" in the denominator of the integrand seems peculiar. Did you mean "$f(z)-f(a)$" or "$f'(z)-f'(a)$" instead?

Comment: @MPW The problem says $f(z)-f'(a)$, but you may assume as either $f(z)-f(a)$ or $f'(z)-f'(a)$ if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Since $f(z)$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $a$, it can be represented by its Taylor series

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)(z-a)^n}{n!}$$

Then, we can write

$$\oint_{C}\frac{1}{f(z)-f(a)}\,dz=\oint_{C}\frac{1}{f'(a)(z-a)\left(1+g(z)\right)}\,dz$$

where $g(z)$ is analytic and $g(a)=0$.

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Thanks! I solved it!

Comment: You're welcome.  Pleased to hear that you have it!